# Bigcommerce template is not applied on localhost

Tags: bigcommerce

I uploaded a new template, let's call it `my-template`, using stencil tool. The template file is placed in folder `pages/custom/page/my-template`. I can select the template in the Template dropdown section on admin page, so I assumed the template is uploaded successfully.

The problem is that, when I preview this page, the template is applied, but on my local, the custom template is not applied (instead, it uses the default `page` template). Is there any step or any setting missing here? What can I do to work with `my-template` on localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're working locally, your `.stencil` file controls the mapping between custom templates and the pages they should be assigned to. Here's an example that would apply the custom my-template file to a webpage whose URL is /about-us/ :

```
{
  "normalStoreUrl": "http://mystore.mybigcommerce.com",
  "port": 3000,
  "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "accessToken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "customLayouts": {
    "brand": {},
    "category": {},
    "page": {
    "my-template.html": "/about-us/"
    },
    "product": {}
  }
}
```

**Note:** After you edit your `.stencil` file, you'll want to re-start the CLI to see your changes applied

https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/template-files/custom-templates/authoring-testing-uploading-custom-templates#authoring-testing-uploading_local-mapping

Answer (score 0):

You must define templates locally in .stencil, then restart stencil to see changes.
**Map each /url/ to the custom-template.html.**

```
    "customLayouts": {
        "product": {
          "featured-product.html": ["/special-product-one", "/special-product-two"],
        "clearance-product.html": "/clearance-product"
    },
    "brands": {},
    "categories": {},
    "page": {
       "fluid-width.html": "/home/"
    }
```